# PHP protecting SQL login data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I'm doing this,

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", 'root', 'password')
```

is it possible for someone visiting the website to get that data, or is there a safer better way to handle MySQL logins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web server is configured properly, it should be very difficult for a cybercreep to view the source code of your php pages. So the password to your Mysql server *should theoretically* be hard to obtain.

But web servers are complex and cybercreeps regularly discover and exploit new security flaws. For example, somebody may find a way to break in to your web server by exploiting a flaw in ssh or a remote desktop protocol. In that case, it doesn't matter how well your https server protects your php page code: the cybercreep can still see it.

So, you should not use your MySql `root` account to deliver database service to your php web app. Instead, use a single purpose MySql account with access only to the database used by your web app.  That way, if a cybercreep does crack your web server, they don't automatically crack your entire MySql server too.

This suggestion is an example of *defense in depth*. It helps slow down cybercreeps even if they do manage to break in to something.

Answer (score -1):

Since this line of code is within a .php file, no visitor (connecting to your web server with http) will be able to see it.

Comment: when you say connecting to web server with http, you mean theres other other ways to connect to obtain the php file?

Comment: Of course. Guessing your ssh password might be one way to connect.